# Which tool can I use for replacing appBuilder/procedure editor?

Tags: ide, programming

As mentioned in [quite some questions on Progress-4GL](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A4279155%20%5Bprogress-4gl%5D%20%5Bopenedge%5D), I'm working with the appBuilder and the corresponding procedure editor for developing windows and procedures for ABL database handling.

Regularly I received the comment to stop using those old-fashioned tools and go for a more recent development environment, but now there seem to exist several ones:

- Progress Developer Studio
- OpenEdge Studio

I'd like to know about those tools? Which one is the most recent, the most elaborated, and obviously which one is cheapest (or even for free), based on the fact that I have a license for working with tools I mentioned before.

As far as the tags on my question are concerned, there seems not to exist a tag for the Progress-4GL programming language. Which one can I add?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the product naming is confusing and has changed a lot.

You need the eclipse based Progress Developer Studio for OpenEdge, aka PDSOE. I would recommend using 12.2 (LTS) or the most recent version 12.3. I would not use anything older than 11.7 .

Comment: Thanks the reply. Just a quick remark: the tag "progress-4gl" you mention exists on StackOverflow, but not on this site.

Comment: you could try downloading a Progress Openedge Developer kit classroom edition first.   I have no experience with it but I think it includes pdsoe